# In how many ways can we distribute $2$ types of gifts?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

The problem: In how many ways can we distribute $2$ types of gifts, $m$ of the first kind and $n$ of the second to $k$ kids, if there can be kids with no gifts?

From the stars and bars method i know that you can distribute m objects to k boxes in $\binom{m+k-1}{k-1}$ ways.
So in my case i can distribute m gifts to k kids in $\binom{m+k-1}{k-1}$ ways, same for n gifts i can distribute them in $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$ ways.
So now if we have to distribute m and n gifts we can first distribute m gifts in $\binom{m+k-1}{k-1}$ ways, then n gifts in $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$ ways, so in total we have: $$\binom{m+k-1}{k-1} \cdot \binom{n+k-1}{k-1} \quad \textrm{ways.}$$
Is my reasoning correct?
What about when we have to give at least 1 gift to each kid, can we do that in $$\binom{m-1}{k-1} \cdot \binom{n+k-1}{k-1}+\binom{n-1}{k-1} \cdot \binom{m+k-1}{k-1}  \quad \textrm{ways?}$$
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, your reasoning is correct

Comment: @mode_er Thank you very much! After looking into it i modified the second answer a bit, is that also correct?

Comment: Hm, I don't think so. Your second answer assumes that if each kid gets one gift, then each kid must get only at least one of either the first gift or only at least one of the second gift, when in reality, the requirement can be satisfied just by every kid getting at least one gift, not necessarily of the same kind. Your reasoning is correct so far, you just need to interpolate for the cases in between, which unless you have an identity at hand to use, might result in an "ugly" answer. I'll do some research to see if such an identity exists

Comment: @mode_er This is how i came up with that answer. The number of ways you can distribute gifts to kids such that every kid gets at least one gift is $\binom{m-1}{k-1}$, so i thought if i first give at least one of the first kind there wouldn't be any restrictions to giving the second, but then we can also give out the second kind of gift first and give out the rest of the first kind without any restrictions. 
As you mentioned i think this may count some ways twice but i can't figure out how to remove those. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning for the problem where kids with no gifts are allowed is correct. To solve the main problem you need to apply the [PIE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) to exclude cases where one or more kids get no gift. You will obtain:

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{k} (-1)^i\binom ki\binom{n+k-1-i}{n}\binom{m+k-1-i}{m}.
$$

Comment: Thank you for answering , but can you explain it just a bit why this works. You are first counting the number of ways that there can be kids with no gifts, then you take away the number of ways n-1 and m-1 gifts can be distributed but this takes away too much so you add the ways that n-2 and m-2 can be distributed and so on? Also does the $\binom{k}{i}$ take away and/or add the repeated counting of gifts that are given to a kid? If you could explain it a bit it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Neti. In general it is very similar to what you wrote. First we are counting  the number of ways that there can be kids with no gifts, then we choose a kid with no gift and take away the number of ways $n$ and $m$ gifts can be distributed between the rest $k-1$ kids. But this takes away too much so we choose a pair of kids with no gift and add the ways that $n$ and $m$ gifts can be can be distributed between the rest $k-2$ kids and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much!